# How to solve 'AttributeError' in kivy python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am making a Python kivy app and getting this attribute error with every code I run.

This is the python code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = Builder.load_string("login.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```

This is the .kv code

```
#:import FirebaseLoginScreen firebaseloginscreen.FirebaseLoginScreen
#:import utils kivy.utils
FloatLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    FirebaseLoginScreen:
        size_hint: 1,1
        pos_hint: {"top": 1, "right": 1}
        web_api_key: "AIzaSyB8JZWB1gzdDq3YAFXwHaJkXyAyyJ6uR44"
        primary_color: utils.get_color_from_hex("#EE682A")
        secondary_color: utils.get_color_from_hex("#060809")
        tertiary_color: utils.get_color_from_hex("#434343")

        on_login_success:
            print("Success")
```

This is the error I get when I run it.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/aayus/Desktop/PersonalProject/Cubing/loginpy.py", line 4, in <module>
     kv = Builder.load_string("login.kv")
   File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 399, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)
   File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 130, in __getattr__
     raise AttributeError
 AttributeError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
kv = Builder.load_string("login.kv")
```

to:

```
kv = Builder.load_file("login.kv")
```

Comment: `
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/aayus/Desktop/PersonalProject/Cubing/loginpy.py", line 5, in <module>
     kv = Builder.load_file("login.kv")
   File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 405, in load_string
     rule_children=rule_children)

Comment: File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 616, in _apply_rule
     cls = Factory_get(cname)
   File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 131, in __getattr__
     raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <FirebaseLoginScreen>
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @programmer Ask a new question about your new error. Or even better, read the error first, it's fairly clear. Where do you believe the FirebaseLoginScreen class is defined?