# My app consists with three buttons with window switching. How do you solve Attribute Error release?

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

Here is my code. Basically I am doing this for my project, whereby I am trying to create a main menu, with three different button events that allows switches to different screens (one for a survey, one for a hyperlink, and one for a checklist).  I tried diagnosing the problem, and I just do not get the attribute error.

**Test integration.ky**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen

class FirstWindow(Screen):
pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
pass

class ThirdWindow(Screen):
pass

class WindowManager (ScreenManager):
pass

kv = Builder.load_file("Test Integration.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
def build(self):
return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
MyMainApp().run()
```

**Test integration.kv**

```
WindowManager:
FirstWindow:
SecondWindow:
ThirdWindow:

\<FirstWindow\>:
name: "Main Menu"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
    
        Label:
            text: "Safety Checklist"
            font_size: 24
            on_release: app.root.current = "Checklist"
            root.manager.transition = "left"


    name: "Test Button."

    Button:
        text: "Please complete our survey!"
        on_release:
            import webbrowser
            webbrowser.open('https://forms.gle/k6cfYEU1snzpykxY9')


    name: "Checklist"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
    
        Label:
            text: "Checklist: Do you acquired all the necessary safety equipment?"
            font_size: 24
    
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
    
            Label:
                text: "Do you have your safety gloves with you?"
                font_size:16
            CheckBox:
                on_active: root.checkbox_click(self, self.active, "Do you have your safety gloves with you?")
            Label:
                text: "Do you have your safety boots with you?"
                font_size:16
            CheckBox:
                on_active: root.checkbox_click(self, self.active, "Do you have your safety boots with you?")
            Label:
                text: "Do you have your safety goggles with you?"
                font_size:16
            CheckBox:
                on_active: root.checkbox_click(self, self.active, "Do you have your safety goggles with you?")
            Label:
                text: "Do you have your helmet with you?"
                font_size:16
            CheckBox:
                on_active: root.checkbox_click(self, self.active, "Do you have your helmet with you?")
    
        Label:
            id: output_label
            text: "You are recommended to acquire or purchase the missing safety equipment."
    
    Button:
        text: "Return to main menu."
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "Main Menu"
            root.manager.transition = "right"
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\nicho\\PycharmProjects\\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\lang\\builder.py", line 729, in \_apply_rule
raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: release

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\nicho\\PycharmProjects\\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\\Test Integration.py", line 17, in \<module\>
kv = Builder.load_file("Test Integration.kv")
File "C:\\Users\\nicho\\PycharmProjects\\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\lang\\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
return self.load_string(data, \*\*kwargs)
File "C:\\Users\\nicho\\PycharmProjects\\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\lang\\builder.py", line 407, in load_string
self.\_apply_rule(
File "C:\\Users\\nicho\\PycharmProjects\\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\lang\\builder.py", line 660, in \_apply_rule
child.apply_class_lang_rules(
File "C:\\Users\\nicho\\PycharmProjects\\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\uix\\widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
Builder.apply(
File "C:\\Users\\nicho\\PycharmProjects\\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\lang\\builder.py", line 540, in apply
self.\_apply_rule(
File "C:\\Users\\nicho\\PycharmProjects\\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\lang\\builder.py", line 736, in \_apply_rule
raise BuilderException(
kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\\Users\\nicho\\PycharmProjects\\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\\Test Integration.kv", line 17:
...
15:            font_size: 24
16:            on_release:

> > 17:                app.root.current = "Checklist"
> > 18:                root.manager.transition = "left"
> > 19:
> > ...
> > AttributeError: release
> > File "C:\\Users\\nicho\\PycharmProjects\\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\lang\\builder.py", line 729, in \_apply_rule
> > raise AttributeError(key)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918598/how-to-solve-attributeerror-in-kivy-python

Answer (score 0):

you should add the screens manually and give them names

```
Builder.load_file("Test Integration.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        _my_top_widget = WindowManager()
        _my_top_widget.add_widget(FirstWindow(name='FirstWindow'))
        _my_top_widget.add_widget(SecondWindow(name='Main Menu'))
        _my_top_widget.current = "FirstWindow"
        return _my_top_widget
```

inside the kv file don't do multi-line functions, make a function in your widget to do the actions you want.

```
        Button:
            text: "Return to main menu."
            on_release: root.return_main()
#                app.root.current = "Main Menu"
#                root.manager.transition = "right"
```

and in your widget class definition you can make a function

```
class FirstWindow(Screen):

    def return_main(self):
        print("return main")
        # app.root.current = "Main Menu"
        # root.manager.transition = "right"
```

this will get you part of the way there.

finding attribute errors in kv files can be tough, especially with stackoverflow formatting because it can be difficult to track the white space.  I was able to execute the code after I made some adjustments but I didn't complete the part of causing the screen transition.

Comment: Thanks man! Really appriciate it!